# Time Series, Point Detection Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series, statistics

[image]I have time series data generated from the sensor. Now I know the the actual point I need to find is at the 11:50, as you can see in the graph this point dooes not hold any statistical property which I can give to detect this point. Any idea how to find this point as process is getting completed at this point?

What library or the algorithm I should use to find this point in time series?

The data I have provided is the historical data, I need to provide this data to algorithm, which can detect such point when streaming data is given to this algortihm. I needed any ideas hoe can I build this algorithm for the point to  detected.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EDjF.png)

[image]

Comment: Could you maybe give a little bit more insight in what you are trying to do? If you already know that you need the value at 11:50, why don't you simply pick it from your dataset? And what do you need the value at that timestep for?

Comment: If there is no statistical property to distinguish it, how do you know it’s the right point?

Comment: As this is historical data, actual process was observed and time was recorded when the process was complete.

Comment: How do you know the process is complete?

Comment: We record this data in lab, by actaully observing the machineary, we know the process is complete. Now we have to link this to the data that is recorded to the sensor.